# git default branch is always pointing to master even after changing config

Tags: git, rbtools

I dont have a branch called master in my git repository but when i do `post-review` command (rbtools addon for git) , its pointing to `master` branch though i point `mainBranch` branch

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=ssh://****
branch.mainBranch.remote=origin
branch.mainBranch.merge=refs/heads/main
reviewboard.url=https:**
tracking.branch=origin/mainBranch
```

command issued from `dev` branch to post code review against `mainBranch` :

```
post-review --parent mainBranch
```

Error :

```
   >  git merge-base origin/master refs/heads/dev Failed to execute command:
 ['git', 'merge-base', 'origin/master', 'refs/heads/dev']
    > fatal: Not a valid object name origin/master
```

Above error clearly shows it is trying to post review against master branch which is not present in my git repo. But i have mainBranch . i need to point to mainBranch so that the command works. i am not sure where to change this in git config or rbtools config ?
Please suggest

FYI - RBT tools : https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/rbtools/dev/

Answer (score 0):

When using Git, rbt post makes the assumption that the closest upstream branch for the diff will be origin/master. You can use --tracking-branch option to get around the error

`post-review --tracking-branch=mainBranch`

https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/rbtools/dev/rbt/commands/post/#tracking-branches